# OnInput event not working anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery

My friends, the code below used to work in Chrome till version 52.x but in the newest version it does not work anymore. Does any of you have any idea why it does not work?

https://jsfiddle.net/2jtrs2m2/

```
<input type="text" id="test" />

<script type="text/javascript">

var my_event = document.createEvent("TextEvent");    
my_event.initTextEvent("textInput",true,false,window,"T");

document.getElementById("test").focus();

document.getElementById("test").dispatchEvent(my_event);

</script>
```

Usually when I executed this code, Chrome would insert the character T in the input. I dont want to use   document.getElementById("xxx").value = "T"   cause in some very specific cases I am working on, I really can only use the code above firing the oninput event which for some reason is not working anymore.

Comment: strange! your event data is there console.log(my_event.data); shows the "T" . I'll be interested on the solution :-) Although I think it's a chrome issue

Comment: Yeap, you are correct. It is really strange, in the console it looks fine.

Comment: I can confirm that updating from Chrome  52.0.2743.116 to 53.0.2785.116 breaks this.

Comment: @Paul-Jan thank you. Do you know if I can report this as a bug to someone at Chromium or it may be a "feature"? Cause this breaks at least 8 websites that I use this exactly same code above. I already read the release notes of the last 2 versions of Chrome and could not find any info about this behaviour being changed :(

Comment: "Events generated by script will no longer trigger default actions, improving spec compliance and browser interop." in http://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/chrome-53-beta-shadow-dom.html

Comment: @int32_t do you know if there is any chrome switch to disable that? Or if not, where can I download any 52.x version of chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using document.execCommand
ie;
`document.execCommand("insertText", false, "foo");`

Comment: Worked :) It would be nice if it would be possible to only fire execComand on an specific input